# System Reserve/Windows 11 Update

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

Hopefully this won't be too convoluted. I started by trying to convert an MBR disk to GPT. I was doing this so I can enable secure boot in the BIOS and then I would have the requirements to upgrade to Windows 11. I tried MBR2GPT.exe but the process failed. Also tried AOMEI Partition Assistant but it couldn't complete the task because it said my system reserve is on a different hard drive than the boot drive - not sure how this happened. Looking into this, it doesn't seem to difficult to move the system reserve to the boot drive using diskpart. The problem is that the system reserve is not in a separate partition on the drive (see image). So how do I resolve this? There are commands to recreate the system reserve on the boot drive, then I could convert the drive to GPT I think? But what about the system reserve on the other disk? Any guidance would be appreciated.

**Partitions:**
[image]

**AOMI Error:**
[image]

Comment: If you want assistance you’ll need to give us specific errors and details on the reasons MBR2GPT failed. Your screenshot doesn’t have the required information to diagnose the reasons MBR2GPT failed. How many partitions do you have on your system disk? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: [This](https://www.diskpart.com/articles/move-system-reserved-partition-4348.html) explains one method to clone and replace the system reserved partition. Before doing any method be sure you create a restorable backup of your partition

Comment: I've added a new image. As you can see, I don't know how I would move the system reserve as it is not in a separate partition on the drive.

Comment: Your new screenshot does not show the necessary information from Disk Management. Instead of trying to crop the screenshot, take a screenshot of the entire application's window and upload that to your question body.  I am voting to close this question until such time you have provided enough information to diagnose the reason MBR2GPT is failing.

Comment: Here's an image of the whole section:

https://imgur.com/bQZUDlO

Comment: You need to upload that image by editing your question. Furthermore, specify the reason, MBR2GPT failed. Your system disk is a single partition. I suspect that’s the reason it failed. There isn’t enough room on the drive to perform any of the required tasks.  **I can’t deal with the ads on Imgur.** I don’t see any disk with the partition your asking about which is confusing.

Comment: Edited my post with new photos and more. info. Last try.

Comment: You could try to set boot and system to be on the same disk by preparing a Windows boot media, disconnecting physically all the disks except C:, then booting and executing Startup Repair. Take good backups before, perhaps an image of the disk and a boot-disk that can return it, if problem occurs. This is also a good advice before running MBR2GPT.

Comment: "MBR2GPT.exe but the process failed" - How?

Comment: Error:
Validating layout disk sector size is; 512 bytes
Disk layout validation failed for disk 3

Disk 3 is my C drive with the OS